# ansible auto user selection in playbook

Tags: ansible

### I have a simple playbook that I run on new managed nodes for Ansible
the playbook has 3 roles : create ansible admin user on destination host , copy ssh key , sets sudo no passwd for ansible user
I have Rhel based nodes and also debian based nodes
for Rhel I use root , for debian root not used by default and I keep it that way so I have a different admin user called sysadmin
I am trying to find  a way that the playbook will identify the OS and choose either root or sysadmin user to run the Play , and also use a proper password from a file in ansible vault
thanks
this is the playbook

- name: init managed node
  user: root
  hosts: init_clients
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  vars:
  user: ansible-admin
  passwd: password-hash

  roles:

  - create_admin_user
  - set_authorized_key
  - set_no_pass

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? The [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) includes examples of how to make things conditional on your distribution name.

Answer (score 1):

100% real code.  But if I didn't have it at my fingertips, I would skip answering this question, as there's no indication of any effort on your part.

```yaml
- name: Set the system user name for Ubuntu
  set_fact:
    linux_system_user: ubuntu
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: Set the system user name for CentOS
  set_fact:
    linux_system_user: centos
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'

- name: Set the system user name for RedHat
  set_fact:
    linux_system_user: root
  when: ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue is that Ansible still needs to run the first Playbook as some user
if that user is the same for all systems (root for example).

That's ok if the user is not the same.

I have to run the playbook once for Rhel and once for Debian and then change the "user" statement to a differener user.